# How to deal with Negative and Positive eigenvalues in this diagonal matrix and what is its time complexity?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Assume:

$$ C= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 5 \\ 2 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 0 & 4 & 3 \\ 3 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\ 5 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ D= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

If the matrices $C$ and $D$ can be written in a diagonal format. Suppose that λ and µ are eigenvalues of matrix C and Matrix D arranged in descending and ascending order.

we will simply have for an arbitrary and orthogonal P (not exactly permutation matrix P), the following relation **(1)** :

Min_PP^T=I Trace(CP^TDP) = sum__(i,j) (λ µ)

My Questions are :

1. when I do calculate the eigenvalues from positive integer matrices C and D (my case study), the results are positive and negative eigenvalues , so
2. How can I sort λ and µ in descending and ascending to continue calculate its multiplication relation ? Are their signs considered in the order?
3. What does the negative values means? How to deal with their approximate numbers? Hence, the relation between λ and µ (1) is considered a lower bound for my problem which only accepts positive integer numbers.
4. what is the time complexity of this method?

For more details : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVs34NrzE8-S3Nau-X0CX7UeXEBo25ff/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a [quick tutorial and basic reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on Meta Math.SE which covers formatting arrays as matrices.  I'll convert your first paragraph to give you a starting point.